# Json data not get in terminal & get error->(SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input)

Tags: json, express, youtube-api

I am trying to get some value from Youtube Api. Now, My express code is->

```
    https.get("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id=qW_SWM1wpMA&key=MYAPIKEY",function(res){
    res.on("data",function(data){
    const da=JSON.parse(data); 
    console.log(da);  
})
});
```

Now, I am console log the data what's coming from api. But I get this error->

```
 $ node app.js
Port is running
undefined:13
        "description": "\"Bang Bhaja\" shows how Nonte and Fonte makes a trick to punish Keltu for punishing them from Superintendent Sir for eating the Ilish Maach.\n\nNonte Fonte is a Bengali comic-strip creation of Narayan Debnath which originally was serialized for the childre



SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\youtube\app.js:13:19)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at IncomingMessage.Readable.read (_stream_readable.js:514:10)
    at flow (_stream_readable.js:987:34)
    at resume_ (_stream_readable.js:968:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
```

But when paste the API link (what's mention in above in https.get method) in chrome I get the json data successfully. **Then why not i getting the json data in terminal?**

[image: Json data in chrome]

Comment: Why arnt you using the google apis Node js client library why are you making the calls manually?

Comment: I was look through the document part of googleapis Node.js client library, but there using blogger. But I use the youtube api v3 not the blogger api. In addition I was use the googleapis but i get error 403(They told that I need a blogger api v3 & activate it).    Then what should I do? I should use only youtube api v3 for fetching an particular video's information.

Comment: In addition Why I am not making the calls manually?